# UIViewController initialization in Swift throws compile error

Tags: swift

I'm trying to instantiate a UIViewController with the designated initializer and a xib file View.xib like so

```
var appBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
var controller = UIViewController.init(nibName: "View", bundle: appBundle)
```

But I get the compile error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

Is anyone else getting this error? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead:

```
var appBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
var controller = UIViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: appBundle)
```

Comment: Oh yes it works now thanks. the documentation points out the init function though https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle: So i'm guessing it's most probably a bug in xcode